# In Bubble Chart how to pass Labels [Label will be value in X Axis and not just any text] for X Axis rather than bubble chart calculate it dynamically

Tags: chart.js

I have a bubble Chart and I am passing the values for plotting the charts.
The bubble Chart Automatically calculates the Labels for the X-Axis but I want to set it or hardcode it rather than bubble Chart doing it.

```
this.chart = new Chart(htmlRef, {
  type: 'bubble',
  data: {
    // labels: ["0", "60", "120", "180", "240", "300"],
    datasets: [
      {
        type:'line',
        label: 'CPU Usage',
        //data: [10,20],
        data: [{x:0,y:5,r:5},{x:10,y:20},{x:15,y:30},{x:25,y:40},{x:55,y:30},{x:80,y:40}],
        borderColor: '#4333FF',
        backgroundColor: '#3398FF',
        fill: true,
        borderWidth: 2
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips:{
      callbacks:{
        label:function(tooltip){
          console.log(tooltip);
          return ("CPU Utilization : "+tooltip.yLabel);
        }
      }
    },
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: "right"
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          display: true,
          gridLines: {
            lineWidth: 2,
            drawBorder: true
            ]

          },
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Time'
          }
        }],
      yAxes: [
        {
          display: true,
          stacked: true,
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Utilization'
          },
          ticks: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,

            // forces step size to be 5 units
            stepSize: 30
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

I expect to set Labels myself like it should be [0,30,60,90,120 ] or if i want to change it on click of button , it should change to [0,60,120,180,240,300].
At any point in time, I can update the Labels in X-Axis.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Your bubble chart is a little odd in that you are only drawing a line on it. Is this for example purposes or could you simply switch the whole chart to `type: line` (since this would solve your problem)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chart.js Bubble chart with custome X-axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37781024/chart-js-bubble-chart-with-custome-x-axis-labels)

Comment: I want to draw points even between the Grids and therefor that's not possible with Line Charts .
That's the reason I had to use Bubble chart .
The look and feel of the chart should be exactly like this except that i should be able to set the labels in the X Axis myself rather than chart calculating itself.